# Malloc an array of an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

**Objective**

Dynamically create an array of an array of Element strucs (defined below)

```
typedef struct {
    void* data;
    } Element;
```

**Question**

I know how to malloc an array of Element strucs

```
Element* arrayOfElements = malloc(4 * sizeof(Element));
```

But then how do I Malloc an array of the above? (an array of arrayOfElements)

**Question 2**

Lets say the array of arrayOfElements is called arrayOfArrayStruc how would I proceed to set values inside of it

For Example I want to copy 65 to arrayOfElements[2] which is inside arrayOfArrayStruc[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XezoV.png) how would I got about that ?

I know how to do that if I wanted to copy 65 straight to arrayOfElements[2]

```
arrayOfElements[2].data = malloc( sizeof(int) );
ptr = arrayOfElements[2].data;
*ptr = 65;
```

but im not sure how to do that if arrayOfElements[2] is inside arrayOfArrayStruc[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XezoV.png).

**EDIT**

To make it more clear my goal i've made a picture

[image: Diagram Of my goal]

So in green is the structure Element defined by

```
typedef struct {
    void* data;
    } Element;
```

Then in red ( which had 4 green boxes) is an Array of Element structures which I malloc'd using

```
Element* arrayOfElements = malloc(4 * sizeof(Element));
```

What im looking to do is store the above ^^ in an array or make an array of pointers (which is the blue box with red boxes in it)

So in the picture "Array Of Element" holds 4 Element Structures, then I want to make an array to store 4 "Array Of Element" (or an array of 4 pointers to point to each "Array of Element")

Comment: I think you don't want that. The data structure you are thinking of is not really good if you can use `struct`s you can write your "*array*" as a structure and have an array of that.

Comment: im not 100% sure if I follow you sorry

Comment: An array of arrays is almost always A TERRIBLE thing in my experience. Normally, scientist (I am one) represent data like this because it seems natural, but very often it's not the *NATURAL* way to do it as a programmer.

Comment: Your diagram doesn't represent the code you have so far... if the red is supposed to mean the pointer `arrayOfElements`  , then that does not contain the green elements. The green elements are in their own block, and the pointer points to it.  An array contains its elements , a pointer is a separate thing to an array, and it points to the first element of an array.

Comment: Right yeah, the pic is kinda how I pictured it but, not how it works I did some  reading and I now get what you were trying to tell me thanks :) . @Anders K diagram is how it works, and is what I was ( well should of been ) going for .... saying that it seems pretty obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array of Element* then you could do something like this where is `n` is the number of pointers:

```
Element** arrayOfStructs = malloc( n* sizeof(Element*) );
```

So for n = 4; you get an array of 4 pointers:

arrayOfStructs

```
+---+
|   | ->
+---+
|   | ->
+---+
|   | ->
+---+
|   | ->
+---+
```

Now allocate for each entry in the arrayOfStructs so if `m` is the number of Elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  arrayOfStructs[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(Element));
}
```

Since each element has a data pointer, you need to allocate what that points to as well:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  arrayOfStructs[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(Element));
  for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
  {
    arrayOfStructs[i][j].data = malloc(sizeof(int));
  }
}
```

After this you will have the following in memory:

Let's say m = 3;

arrayOfStructs

```
+---+    +---+---+----+
|   | -> |   |   |    |  array of Elements
+---+    +---+---+----+    +---+---+----+
|   | -------------------> |   |   |    |
+---+    +---+---+----+    +---+---+----+
|   | -> |   |   |    |
+---+    +---+---+----+    +---+---+----+
|   | -------------------> |   |   |    |
+---+                      +---+---+----+
```

each element in "array of Elements" 1..3(or rather 0..2) point to a different "data" (below  on array of Elements is turned around 90 degrees so I can more easily draw boxes):

```
+---+    +---+
|   | -> |   | integer
+---+    +---+   +---+
|   | ---------> |   |
+---+            +---+     +---+
|   | -------------------> |   |
+---+                      +---+
```

Comment: So  how would I make, lets say the 2nd element of arrayOfElements which is pointed by the 3rd element of arrayOfStrucs 

I can do it with just arrayOfElements  but im not sure how to do it when it is pointed by arrayOfStrucs

Answer (score 1):

`arrayOfElements` is the name of a pointer variable. You cannot have an array of names.

You could have an array of pointer variables. You can write the code for that, it is the same as the code for an array of int, but use a pointer type instead of int.  Then, you would need to initialize each of those pointer variables in the array the same way as you are doing now.

However, as posted, the question asked for "array of arrays", not "array of pointers".  An "array of arrays" is an array where the element type is an array (not a pointer).

Here is a non-dynamically-allocated array: `int x[4][5];` . This is an array of 4 elements, with each element being an array of 5 ints.

To dynamically allocate one of these, it is the same code as dynamically allocating any array of 4 elements.  We just use `int[5]` as the element type, instead of `int` or whatever.

The type of the pointer to the first element is: "pointer to `int[5]`".  In C syntax this is written `int (*)[5]`  -- not `int *[5]` which is an array of pointers.

One way to write the code would be:

```
int (*px)[5] = malloc(4 * sizeof(int[5]));
```

hopefully you can see the similarity between this and the `malloc` in your question. We just replaced `Element` with `int[5]`. (So, your job now, is to use `Element[5]` instead of `int[5]`. Or whatever size instead of `5`).

To avoid repetition (and so avoid the possibility of errors) it's possible to use the common idiom:

```
int (*px)[5] = malloc(4 * sizeof *px);
```

which is 4 elements each of the right size for what the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: So lets say I want arrayOfStrucs have  5 elements ( elements being arrayOfElements which in turn have 4 elements ) so would I do : Element* arrayOfStrucs[5] = malloc(5 * sizeof(arrayOfElements[4]));

Comment: @CrispyCashew No, try again :) (Look at the last line of code in my answer and change `int` for `Element`, and swap over all the `4` and `5`).

Comment: Element (*px)[5] = malloc(5 * sizeof(Element[4]));

Comment: was me saying 5 * sizeof(arrayOfElements[4])); correct? as I want to allocate enough memory to fit 5 of arrayOfElements[4] (which then contain 4 Element structs) .

Comment: That is 5 rows of 4 elements. I thought you said you wanted 4 rows of 5 elements in your first comment. But either way you must match the size on the left with the size in the `sizeof`.

Comment: Right when you say 5 rows of 4 elements if we were talking about a Int array it would be int int x[5][4];

Because I want an array of pointers ( because arrayOfElements  are pointers)  In my first comment what I was trying to get across is that I want 
arrayOfStrucs to hold 5  arrayOfElements (arrayOfElements is an array of Strucs)

Comment: is that what you ment also and im just going in circles here?

Comment: Your question said you want an array of arrays. That's different to an array of pointers . My answer focuses on how to make an array of arrays.

Comment: right ok I think thats where im going wrong, for what I want to do  would making an array of pointers would be the way to go ?

Comment: well im not too sure what would be more suitable to store arrayOfElements

Comment: @CrispyCashew I don't know what you mean sorry

Comment: I can edit my question with a picture to try explain myself?

Comment: @CrispyCashew Sure, it's always good idea to edit the question to make it clearer